# Group product and tensor product of irreps

Tags: group-theory

If $D(g_1)$ and $D(g_2)$ are irreps of $G_1$ and $G_2$ (respectively), is $D(g_1) \otimes D(g_2)$ an irreps of $G_1 \times G_2$ ? If yes, could you explain why ?
Is it still the case if $G_1=G_2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can get this from character theory. If $\chi_1$ and $\chi_2$ are
the characters of your two given irreps, then
$$\sum_{g_i\in G_i}|\chi_i(g_i)|^2=|G_i|$$
for $i\in\{1,2\}$. The character of the tensor product is $\chi(g_1,g_2)=\chi_1(g_1)\chi_2(g_2)$. Therefore
$$\sum_{(g_1,g_2)\in G_1\times G_2}|\chi(g_1,g_2)|^2
=\sum_{g_1\in G_1}\sum_{g_2\in G_2}|\chi(g_1)|^2|\chi(g_2)|^2=|G_1|
|G_2|=|G_1\times G_2|$$
so that $\chi$ is an irreducible character.